# org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for all conditions to be valid

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am new to selenium, So very limited knowledge about the selenium. Here I am facing intermittent timeout issue for internet explorer. I had tried increasing timeout still it fails sometimes.

**Error stack trace:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for all conditions to be valid: visibility of all elements located by By.xpath: /*//table[@class='urMatrixLayout urHtmlTableReset']//tr//table//tr//td//div//div/span[contains(text(),'Violations')] && element to be clickable: By.xpath: /*//table[@class='urMatrixLayout urHtmlTableReset']//tr//table//tr//td//div//div/span[contains(text(),'Violations')] (tried for 120 second(s) with 1000 milliseconds interval)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'WIN-2PRR06VLLDC', ip: 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx', os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_241'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities {browserAttachTimeout: 0, browserName: internet explorer, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enableElementCacheCleanup: true, enablePersistentHover: false, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.enableFullPageScreenshot: true, ie.ensureCleanSession: true, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true, ignoreZoomSetting: true, initialBrowserUrl: , javascriptEnabled: true, nativeEvents: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, requireWindowFocus: false, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: dismiss, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss, version: 11}
```

I have implemented code in the following way

```
 public static void clickOnElement(By element, String comment, WebDriver driver) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
    wait.pollingEvery(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
    wait.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.and(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(element),
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)));
    WebElement context = driver.findElement(element);
    wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    });
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    context.click();
    log.info("Clicked on element " + comment);
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

**Html** tree:

```
 `<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="WDCC" ct="ML" lsdata=" 
  {0:'WDCC',7:'LINE'}" class="urMatrixLayout urHtmlTableReset" 
  role="presentation" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody class="urLinStd">
  <tr>
     <td ct="MLC" lsdata="{}" id="WDCE" valign="baseline" align="left" 
  class="urLayoutDefault" style="border-collapse:separate;white- 
  space:normal;"><label ct="L" lsdata=" 
  {1:'WDD1',3:'Business\x20Process',4:true,11:'ENDOFLINE',12:true}" 
  id="WDCF" f="WDD1" class="urL" style="text-align:right;line- 
  height:normal;display:inline-block;min-width:100%;white-space:nowrap;"> 
  <span class="urLblReq">*</span>&nbsp;Business Process:</label></td>
     <td ct="MLC" lsdata="{}" id="WDD0" valign="baseline" align="left" 
  class="urLayoutDefault" style="border-collapse:separate;white- 
  space:normal;">
        <span id="WDD1-r" class="urCoB2Whl ">
           <input id="WDD1" ct="CB" lsdata=" 
  {4:true,7:'WDD2',8:'Basis',10:'Basis'}" lsevents="{Select: 
  [{ResponseData:'delta',ClientAction:'submit'},{}]}" type="text" 
  autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" ti="0" class="urEdf2TxtRadius 
  urEdf2TxtEnbl lsEdf3TxtHlpBtn lsEdfLeftBrdRadius urBorderBox" 
  readonly="" value="Basis" role="combobox" style="width:125px;">
           <div id="WDD1-btn" tabindex="-1" ti="-1" class="lsEdf3HlpBtnStd 
  urBorderBox lsEdf2HlpRadius lsEdf3HlpIcon lsEdf3HlpBtn lsEdf3HlpBtnCoB" 
  role="button" style="display:inline-block;"></div>
        </span>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td ct="MLC" lsdata="{}" id="WDE1" valign="baseline" align="left" 
  class="urLayoutDefault" style="border-collapse:separate;white- 
  space:normal;"><label ct="L" lsdata=" 
  {1:'WDE4',3:'Functional\x20Area',11:'ENDOFLINE',12:true}" id="WDE2" 
  f="WDE4" class="urL" style="text-align:right;line- 
  height:normal;display:inline-block;min-width:100%;white- 
  space:nowrap;">Functional Area:</label></td>
     <td ct="MLC" lsdata="{}" id="WDE3" valign="baseline" align="left" 
  class="urLayoutDefault" style="border-collapse:separate;white- 
  space:normal;">
        <span id="WDE4-r" class="urCoB2Whl ">
           <input id="WDE4" ct="CB" lsdata="{7:'WDE5',10:'Select'}" 
  lsevents="{Select:[{ResponseData:'delta',ClientAction:'submit'},{}]}" 
  type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" ti="0" 
  class="urEdf2TxtRadius urEdf2TxtEnbl lsEdf3TxtHlpBtn lsEdfLeftBrdRadius 
  urBorderBox" readonly="" value="Select" role="combobox" 
  style="width:125px;">
           <div id="WDE4-btn" tabindex="-1" ti="-1" class="lsEdf3HlpBtnStd 
  urBorderBox lsEdf2HlpRadius lsEdf3HlpIcon lsEdf3HlpBtn lsEdf3HlpBtnCoB" 
  role="button" style="display:inline-block;"></div>
        </span>
     </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></td></tr></tbody> 
  </table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></div> 
  </td></tr></tbody></table></span></span></td></tr></tbody></table></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td ct="MLC" lsdata="{}" id="WDE8" valign="bottom" align="left" 
  class="urLayoutPadless" style="border- 
  collapse:separate;width:100%;height:5px;white-space:normal;">
  <div id="WDEA-r">
     <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="WDEA" ct="ML" lsdata=" 
   {0:'WDEA',7:'LINE'}" class="urMatrixLayout urHtmlTableReset" 
   role="presentation" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tbody class="urLinStd">
           <tr>
              <td></td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
   <td ct="MLC" lsdata="{}" id="WDEC" valign="bottom" align="left" 
    class="urLayoutPadless" style="border- 
    collapse:separate;width:100%;white-space:normal;">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="WDED" ct="TS" 
  lsdata="{2:'100\x25',3:'Choose\x20Tab',6:true,7:false,8:false}" 
  lsevents="{TabSelect:[{ResponseData:'delta',ClientAction:'submit'}, 
   {}],Scroll:[{ResponseData:'delta',EnqueueCardinality:'single'}, 
  {}],Hotkey:[{ResponseData:'delta',ClientAction:'submit'},{}]}" class="" 
  role="presentation" style="width:100%;" tabindex="-1" ti="-1">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td valign="bottom" class="lsTbsPanelCnt">
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" 
   style="width:100%;">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td class="lsTbsPanelLeftBtns" align="left"><a 
    class="lsTbsPgPrevLeftDisp lsTbsBtnIcon" tabindex="-1" ti="-1" 
  id="WDED-prevLeft" style="visibility:hidden;"></a></td>
  <td class="lsTbsPanel2" width="90%">
     <span itn="ITBB" id="WDED-ITBB" tabindex="0" ti="0" 
  style="position:absolute;top:-1000;height:1;"></span>
     <div id="WDED-panel" class="lsTbsOvfl" role="tablist" aria- 
  controls="" style="float:left;">
     <div ct="TSITM" lsdata="{0:'WDEE',2:true,12:'WDEF'}" id="WDEE" 
  class="lsTbsEndMore2Sel" style="visibility: visible;">
        <span class="lsTbsFirst2Sel"></span>
        <span role="tab" id="WDEE-focus" tabindex="0" ti="0" 
  class="urNoUserSelect lsTbsLabel2Sel">
           User Access
           <div class="lsTbsTitleAlign" aria-hidden="true" 
   role="presentation">User Access-</div>
        </span>
     </div>
     <div ct="TSITM" lsdata="{0:'WD01B0',1:1,2:true,12:'WD01B1'}" 
   id="WD01B0" class="lsTbsEndMore2" style="visibility: visible;">
     <span class="lsTbsStartEnd2Sel"></span>
     <span role="tab" id="WD01B0-focus" tabindex="0" ti="0" 
   class="urNoUserSelect lsTbsLabel2">
        Violations
        <div class="lsTbsTitleAlign" aria-hidden="true" 
    role="presentation">Violations-</div>
     </span>`
```

**Xpath** :

```
/*//table[@class='urMatrixLayout urHtmlTableReset']//tr//table//tr//td//div//div/span[contains(text(),'Violations')]
```

Comment: `wait.until(...)` - wait until condition is valid or time expire. If time expire, it throws `TimeoutException`. `new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);` - the timeout is 120 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is with this code `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.and(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(element),ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)));`

Both condition are not getting full fill at the same time and after reaching threshold time limit it throws the Timeout Exception.

**Solution:**

Split the and condition to identify which method causing issue:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(element));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
```

Another thing is try to replace `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy` with [visibilityOf(element)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) or [visibilityOfElementLocated(locator)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) in your method.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
```

`visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy` waits until **all the element** on the page get visible and it might be the case that all the element you are locating are not visible on page at same time. This method used for multiple element.

Comment: Thanks Narendra, Your answer help me to gain more understanding about these APIs. Still, i am facing the same issue after refactoring as per your suggestion.  rg.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: /*//table[@class='urMatrixLayout urHtmlTableReset']//tr//table//tr//td//div//div/span[contains(text(),'Violations')] (tried for 120 second(s) with 1000 milliseconds interval). Please check my Xpath and html tree in the question.  is there something like i am providing wrong path?

Comment: @kush, I can't find the matching element with your xpath in HTML tree shared by you. How did you find this xpath? Make it more relative. Use this xpath `//div[@class='lsTbsEndMore2']/span[contains(.,'Violations')]` and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

1. Starting xpath from `/*//table` is the same as starting from `//table`
2. Your xpath is incorrect. If you look at your html you will see that both tables having class `urMatrixLayout urHtmlTableReset` do not contain mentioned text
3. Both conditions check is synchronized in time so at this point everything is okay
4. You can test your code with this path: `//div[@id='WDED-panel']//span[contains(text(), 'Violations')]`